# Parameters by Default on IActionResult .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently have a Dashboard project with a lot of pages. They have a lot of parameters; however, they all have a few parameters in common. In the example below, these would be `companyCode` and `outputMode`

I would like to take all the common parameters and make them automatically included in a new class that still takes in same information as input, but in a more maintainable way.

## Current State

RawController.cs

```
public IActionResult metric1(
  string companyCode 
  , int param1
  , string param2
  , string outputMode = "default"
)
{
  // DO STUFF
  return View();
}

public IActionResult metric2(
  string companyCode 
  , int param3
  , string param4
  , string outputMode = "default"
)
{
  // DO STUFF
  return View();
}
```

## Desired Future State

UNKNOWN.cs (pseudocode)

```
public class CustomActionResult: IActionResult {
  this.companyCode = RouteValueDictionary["companyCode"];
  this.outputMode = RouteValueDictionary["outputMode"];
}
```

RawController.cs

```
public CustomActionResult metric1(
  int param1
  , string param2
)
{
  // DO STUFF
  return View();
}

public CustomActionResult metric2(
  int param3
  , string param4
)
{
  // DO STUFF
  return View();
}
```

Is this possible? 
Am I thinking about this in a totally wrong way?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Is what possible?  What do common input parameters have to do with the output result?

Comment: I just want to increase the maintainability of the code by reducing the size of RawController.cs Output would be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to implement Jacob's answer, I realized I didn't really want to create a custom version of an `IActionResult`, I really wanted to standardize the parameters that were being sent. It ended up being significantly more effective to define these parameters in a model, send them via the HTTP request as JSON, and parse the URL parameters until they fit into that model.

## Solution

metricModel.cs

```
public class standardParams
    {
        public string companyCode { get; set; }
        public string outputMode { get; set; } = "default";
    }
```

RawController.cs

```
public IActionResult metric1( 
  string standard_params
  , int param1
  , string param2 
)
{
  // DO STUFF
  return View();
}

public IActionResult metric2( 
  string standard_params
  , int param3
  , string param4  )
{
  // DO STUFF
  return View();
}
```

Within the IActionResults, I can access the standard params by doing the following:

```
standardParams p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<standardParams>(standard_params);
companyCode = p.companyCode;
outputMode = p.outputMode;
```

For reference, going to `/Raw/metric1?standard_params={companyCode: "test"}&param1=1&param2=test2` gives the following data inside the controller:

`p.companyCode = "test"`

`p.outputMode = "default"`

`param1 = 1`

`param2 = "test2"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a base class instead of or in addition to the interface. Since populating default properties would be part of the *implementation*, you cannot do that through an interface alone.

```
internal abstract class MetricActionResult: IActionResult {
    this.companyCode = RouteValueDictionary["companyCode"];
    this.outputMode = RouteValueDictionary["outputMode"];
}

public class CustomActionResult : MetricActionResult {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This was definitely a useful start. It gave me a way to mess with the `IActionResult` without writing it down every time; however, I wasn't able to actually access the RouteValueDictionary from the abstract class like I was thinking. I ended up making a Model for my request and sending it via a JSON encoded parameter. If it ends up working I'll post it as an answer, but I'm hopeful!